# To get Parent and ChildProcess ID from process ID in Python

Tags: python, process, solaris, rhel

I am trying to get the `ppid` of the process that I want.

I used following code to get the pid

```
proc=subprocess.Popen('ps -ae | grep ruby', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
output=proc.communicate()[0]
str = output.split()
```

Now in the `str[0]`, I have the pid of the process say ruby, I want to get the parent process ID `ppid` and child process ID of the same process.

I need this solution to be run on `Solaris as well as Red Hat Enterprise Linux` 6.0

Is there any way to get that like `getppid()` and `getchildid()`? Or do I need to do it by `grep` command again and splitting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this code is a bad idea. Your code will not work on solaris.
You can use 'psutil' library, that way you can keep your code independent of os.
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

```
p = psutil.Process(7055)
parent_pid = p.ppid()
```

Comment: yes, I am using solaris OS. But I am getting error 'no module named psutil'. How can add it solaris and where. And I want the child process ID

Comment: On python 2 it was not a method, but an attribute: `p.ppid`

Answer (score 1):

I presume there's nothing wrong with os.getppid() .

Shrug.

http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-parameters

Comment: Bit it gives the ppid of the the current running process .i.e. python script. I want to get the ppid and child process of the process which I have given.

Comment: os.getppid doesn't exist for python 2.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your system's `ps` command. On Linux, `ps` will include the PPID for each process with the `-l` flag (among others), so `ps -ale | grep ruby` will include the ruby process id in `str[3]` and ruby's PPID in `str[4]`.